# Container initialization in C++98

Tags: c++, stl, c++98

I have to construct an ordered container (which must be iterable) with the following rule:

> If the condition is true, the container is `{1,0}`, else it's `{0,1}`

I have the following code, but I don't find it "elegant":

```
   vector<int> orderedSides;
   if (condition) 
   {
       orderedSides.push_back(1);
       orderedSides.push_back(0);
   }
   else            
   {
       orderedSides.push_back(0);
       orderedSides.push_back(1);
   }
```

Is there a better way to do this (from concision and performance point of view)?

Comment: You can make a call to reserve before you implement it. Ultimately, the std::initializer_list constructors aren't better from a performance standpoint, as they have to copy data into the container.

Comment: Before C++11 that's basically the only way to do it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude For C++ noobs: what would be the way to do this in C++11?

Comment: @Rightleg `vector<int> orderedSided = { condition, !condition }`. *Iff* `condition` is a `bool` expression. If `condition` is otherwise convertible to `int` (or of course is an `int`) but the result might not be `1` or `0`, then `{ !!condition, !condition }`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Wow that's cool. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. All the answers make it more complicated for nothing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might implement something like this:

```
vector<int> orderedSides(2, 0);
(condition ? orderedSides.front() : orderedSides.back()) = 1;
```

which is a little bit shorter than explicit *if* clauses.

As @Deduplicator mentioned below, we might rewrite the second line in a more concise way:

```
orderedSides[!condition] = 1;
```

Comment: `orderedSides[!condition] = 1;` as the second line is even shorter and relies less on the optimizer.

Comment: @Deduplicator Exactly, perfect note!

Comment: I find this code much harder to read and the intent is very unclear. I don't really like the bool cast either, but that ones just my opinion. The OP should steer clear of this. No down-voting, as the OP did say brevity was the most important thing, it might even be for code golf for example?

Comment: The OP also mentioned performance, and this looks bad performance-wise. You have a input-dependent address, which always aliases one of the two prior stores. That's the sort of thing that an OOO CPU dislikes. @Some programmer dude's answer (in the comments, boo!) looks better as it has two definitely unrelated stores.

Comment: if the condition is true, the array should be in descending order. maybe `[!condition]` would read nicer with a different name, say `[!descending]`

Answer (score 5):

```
vector<int> orderedSides;
orderedSides.push_back(condition ? 1 : 0);
orderedSides.push_back(condition ? 0 : 1);
```

I don't think it's more performant but I find it more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You could compromise between efficiency and avoiding repetition, initialise the first with the condition and the second from the first.

```
vector<int> orderedSides(1, bool(condition)) ;
orderedSides.push_back(!orderedSides.back());
```

Comment: `= { bool(condition) }` is not C++98 as requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
orderedSides.push_back(0);
orderedSides.push_back(1);
if (condition)
  std::iter_swap(orderedSides.begin(), orderedSides.begin()+1);
```

I know this take bits cost. As one of candidates.

Comment: That'd be `std::swap`, since `front` and `back` return references and not iterators.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate a `std::vector` from an array, even in C++98.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    bool condition = false;
    std::cout << "condition is: " << std::boolalpha << condition << '\n';

    int arr[][2] = {{0,1}, {1,0}};
    int index = condition;
    std::vector<int> v(arr[index], arr[index]+2);

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        std::cout << v[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
$ g++ tt.cc && ./a.out
condition is: false
0 1
```

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: How is that constructor implemented in a typical C++03 standard library implementation? Is it just doing a `for` loop over the array internally?

Comment: @CodyGray I'd hope that the implementation would resize/reserve enough memory first. But then, I don't think it makes much of a difference whether you write down a loop or memcpy or std::copy to implement this, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If building the elements (the `int`s in your question, whatever it is in real life) is free and side-effect-less:

```
static const int data[] = { 0, 1, 0 };
std::vector<int> orderedSides (data+condition, data+condition+2);
```

Full program example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> make(bool cond)
{
    static const int data[] = { 0, 1, 0 };
    return std::vector<int> (data+cond, data+cond+2);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    return os << "{ " << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << " }";
}    

int main()
{
    std::cout << "true:  " << make(true) << "\n"
              << "false: " << make(false) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
true:  { 1, 0 }
false: { 0, 1 }
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bc5f755b75dfc77)</kbd>